# Join table on custom columns

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to join table based NOT on their Database-level relationship (PK, FK), but some custom criteria:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u inner join Docs d on u.Doc = d.ISBN
```

and map it to

```
public class User 
{
   public Doc Document { get; set; }
}
public class Doc
{
   public Int64 Id {get; protected set}
   public Int64 Isbn {get; set}
}
```

Is it possible with only mappings or do I need to call some method on Criteria API (which I use)?

I have tried the following:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMapping<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.Id, p => p.Column("Id"););
        ManyToOne(x => x.Document, m =>
        {
            m.Column("Doc");
            m.ForeignKey("ISBN");
            m.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
            m.Access(Accessor.Property);
            m.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
            m.NotNullable(true);
        });
    }
}
public class DocMap : ClassMapping<Doc>
{
    public DocMap()
    {
        Table("Docs");
        Id(x => x.Id, p => 
             { 
                p.Column("Id");   
                p.Generator(Generators.GuidComb); 
             });
        Property(x => x.Isbn, p => 
             { 
                p.Column("ISBN"); 
                p.NotNullable(true); 
             });
    }
}
//2.Criteria API
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria("User")
// ...    
criteria.CreateCriteria("Document", "Docs", JoinType.InnerJoin, docCriterion);
```

but the result is:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u 
    inner join Docs d on u.Doc=d.Id /* docCriterion */ 
    left outer join Docs d2 on u.Doc=d.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
criteria.CreateCriteria("Users")
   .CreateCriteria("Document").Add(Restrictions.Eq("Isbn ", ?);
```

in your query  `u.Doc = d.ISBN` is not correct, cause Doc is `Doc` entity and ISBN is number

Comment: AFAIK, it will ADD ADDTIONAL criteria on join, but I need to modify the main.

Comment: is `Doc` is `User` entity child in mapping ?

Comment: `criteria.CreateCriteria("Document", "Docs", JoinType.InnerJoin, docCriterion)` you don't need this `InnerJoin` your docs already join by mapping, check my updated criteria

Comment: `Doc` is a SQL `int` column so `u.Doc=d.ISBN` is correct. I'am NOT designing this database, I only need to access it and map it to my entities layer.

Comment: Ok, if it is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `WHERE` criteria, I can live with that for now, but I really need this CUSTOM columns `JOIN ON u.Doc=d.ISBN` part

Comment: `public class User 
{
   public Doc Document { get; set; }
}` here Document is Doc object this is what i am saying it is not `int`, and you need to do `HQL` not `SQL` if you want to get it using entity